# A question related to bousfield localization and nilpotent completion

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, localization, completion

I am reading Bousfield's paper entitled "[The localization of spectra with respect to homology](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938379900181)" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=551009)). In that paper,  Corollary 6.13 states that, if a ring spectrum $E$ has countable homotopy and satisfies some vanishing conditions in the associated Adams spectral sequence, then the localization is equivalent to nilpotent completion.

So, my question is the following:

> What are the ring spectra $E$ (I need an updated list)  satisfying the above conditions?

Comment: For reference, Bousfield's paper can be found here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82464212.pdf . Corollary 6.13 is on page 24 (the page number is 280)

Comment: @VictoriaM, thanks!  I have edited in a link to the abstract (which I think is generally to be preferred to the PDF, especially since it's freely available).

Comment: Should your hypothesis "if a ring spectrum $E$ with countable homotopy and satisfies …" be "if a ring spectrum $E$ *has* countable homotopy and satisfies …"?

Comment: @LSpice: Thank you.

Comment: Morava $E$ theories satisfy the condition I think. That's why they are smashing!

Comment: @Prasit: Thank you so much. Yeah, I know if a spectrum is smashing then that definitely sits inside the list. Using 10.6 and 10.9 of Ravenel's paper on "Localization of spectra with respect to certain periodic homology" it follows that  E(n) is smashing. But do you know more examples?